# jQuery's CSS method overriding :hover properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("a.load").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#main").load($(this).attr("href"));
            // alert("#"+($(this).attr("id")));
            $("."+($(this).attr("class"))).css('border-bottom', 'solid 1px black');
            $("."+($(this).attr("class"))).css('background-color', '#F5F5F5');
            $("#"+($(this).attr("id"))).css('border-bottom', 'solid 2px white');
            $("#"+($(this).attr("id"))).css('background-color', 'white');

        });
    });
</script>
```

Above function works as expected, despite the fact that :hover properties for one of my class stop working after calling this function. So it seems that jQuery's CSS method is overriding :hover properties. Is there a workaround for this?

I tried adding at the end of the function:

```
$("."+($(this).attr("class"))+":hover").css('border-bottom', 'solid 2px white');
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: Lets see the css with the `:hover`.

Comment: What's the difference between `$("#"+($(this).attr("id")))` and `$(this)`?

Comment: First would return `#contact`, second: `contact`. Value of attribute `id` withouth `#` at the beginning in CSS would be perceived as an element, not id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just discovered !important tag and it did the job! no more overriding!

```
border-bottom-color: white !important;
border-bottom-width: 2px !important;
background-color: white !important;
```

Comment: IMHO using `!important` is not the best way to go about this.

Comment: may not be the best way, but works like a charm as a quick fix to make the deadline. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is not meant to deal with CSS. pseudo-selectors do not exist in the DOM.

Instead, extract your css, and toggle the class with jQuery (`addClass`/`removeClass`/`toggleClass`)